# Setting Up Rows in Tables

Tags: html, datatables, rows

I'm trying to set up custom notifications for order confirmations and am struggling to find in the documentation how to make sure that each line in a data table row is related to that row.  It that what the order line data fields are versus the just regular sales order data fields?

I'm using MJML to create the more stylized customer facing notifications.

I've looked far and wide through the documentation, googles and blog posts.

```
<mjml>

  <mj-head>

    <mj-style>
        @media all and (max-width: 599px) {
      .container600 {
        width: 100% !important;
      }


      .smarttable {
        border: 0;
      }
      .smarttable thead {
        display:none;
        border: none;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        max-width:0px;
        max-height:0px;
      }
      .smarttable tr {
        display: block;
        width:90%;
        margin:20px auto;
      }
      .smarttable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .smarttable td:before {
        content: attr(data-label);
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    }
    </mj-style>
       <mj-attributes>
               <mj-text align="left" font-family="sans-serif" color="#000" font-size="14px" line-height="23px" />

      <mj-section background-color="#fff" padding="0px" />
    </mj-attributes>

  </mj-head>

  <mj-body background-color="#ededed">

    <mj-section>
   <mj-column>
        <mj-image width="300px" align="center" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/45492/2019-04-05/72zfh7/45492/214936/splitheader_01.jpg" />
      </mj-column>

         <mj-column>
        <mj-image width="300px" align="center" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/45492/2019-04-05/72zfh9/45492/214938/splitheader_02.jpg" />
      </mj-column>
  </mj-section>
        <mj-section>
      <mj-column>

          <mj-text>
        John Smith,<br></br>
            Your order <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#429df1">#((Document.OrderNbr))</a> contains one or more backordered items. Most backorders are filled and shipped out within five business days. We apologize for the inconvenience.
        </mj-text>
               </mj-column>
              </mj-section>   

                <mj-section> <mj-column>
        <mj-button font-family="Helvetica" background-color="#f45e43" color="white" align="left" padding="0px 25px" href="">
          VIEW ORDER DETAILS
         </mj-button>
                  </mj-column>
          </mj-section>

           <mj-section><mj-column>
           <mj-spacer height="15px" />
           </mj-column>
           </mj-section>

<mj-section> <mj-column>
  <mj-text><h1 style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;background-color:#033047; padding:5px">BACKORDER NOTIFICATION</h1></mj-text>
  </mj-column></mj-section>

          <!-- First column -->
          <mj-section> <mj-column>
              <mj-text><h2 style="color:#033047;font-size:16px;">ORDER DETAILS</h2></mj-text>
           <mj-text>Customer #:  ((Document.CustomerOrderNbr))<br>
             Order #:  <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#429df1">((Document.OrderNbr))</a><br>
             Purchase Order #:  ((Document.InvoiceNbr))<br>
             Order Date:  ((Document.OrderDate))</br>  
             Shipping Method:  ((Document.ShipVia.CarrierID))<br>
             Estimated Shipping Date:  ((Document.ShipDate))</br>
            </mj-text></mj-column>
            </mj-section>


<mj-section>

<mj-column>
      <mj-divider border-width="1px" border-style="solid" border-color="black" />
<mj-text>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="min-width:100%;">

<tr>
<td style="padding:5px;">
<table class="smarttable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="min-width:100%;"><thead>
                    <tr><th scope="col" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:10px;line-height:15px;color:#033047;text-align:left;background-color:#ededed">ITEM</th>
                      <th scope="col" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:10px;line-height:15px;color:#033047;text-align:left;background-color:#ededed">SKU</th>
                      <th scope="col" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:10px;line-height:15px;color:#033047;text-align:left;background-color:#ededed">QTY</th>

  <th scope="col" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:10px;line-height:15px;color:#033047;text-align:left;background-color:#ededed">PRICE EACH</th>

                        <th scope="col" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:10px;line-height:15px;color:#033047;text-align:left;background-color:#ededed">ITEM TOTAL</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr><td data-label="ITEM" valign="top" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:20px;">((Document.OrderDesc))</td>

                      <td data-label="SKU" valign="top" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:20px;">((Transactions.InventoryID.InventoryCD))</td>

                      <td data-label="QTY" valign="top" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:20px;">((Transactions.OrderQty))</td>

<td data-label="PRICE EACH" valign="top" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:20px;">((Transactions.CuryUnitPrice))</td>

  <td data-label="ITEM TOTAL" valign="top" style="padding:5px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:20px;">((Transactions.CuryExtPrice))</td>
  </tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table>

</mj-text>
  <mj-divider border-width="1px" border-style="solid" border-color="black" />
</mj-column>
</mj-section>


        <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
      <mj-text>
        <h3 style="color:#033047;font-size:20px; padding-top:25px">SUPPORT & ASSISTANCE</h3></mj-text>

    <mj-text>Feel free to contact us if you need further asisstance.<br></br>
      Phone: 1-888-637-3898<br>
      Email: <a href="mailto:info@graphicproducts.com" target="_blank" style="color:#429df1">info@graphicproducts.com</a></br>
      Website: <a href="GraphicProducts.com" target="_blank" style="color:#429df1">GraphicProducts.com</a><br></br>
        </mj-text>
        </mj-column></mj-section>

  <mj-text align="center"><br>Copyright © 2019, All rights reserved.<br>
    Graphic Products, Inc., 9825 SW Sunshine Ct. Beaverton, OR 97005, United States
    <br>
    View our <a href="https://www.graphicproducts.com/privacy/" target="_blank" style="color:#000">privacy policy</a>
        </mj-text>           

</mj-body>
</mjml>
```

I just need to ensure that rows are related when applicable, and item having the description next to it and then having the total relate to the overall table total.

Answer (score 0):

No one ever got back to me on this but I eventually found a solution and wanted to post it here so that if anyone else ever runs into this they can use it.

The data tables have a special code that needs to go around them that makes the table loop and pull info into it.

See article here: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/07/loops-in-notification-templates.html

Comment: Please consider adding more details apart from just the link,